# Can not click radio button on chrome

Tags: css, radio-button

I have some problem with some radio buttons in Chrome. It works fine on other browsers but when I want to select the middle button I have to click the upper one. If I want to click the bottom one I have to select the middle one.

Can you please help me ?

this is a link of webpage   http://gia-online.com/banjac/vps_hosting.html

The problem is in first price table

Comment: Did not work correct in my FireFox either.

Comment: Hm, I changed values and I still have problem with Chrome. O my Firefox works great. :/

Comment: Found the line of CSS causing the problem.  Do not know why.  On Line 246 of `gia-online.com/banjac/css/style.css` when I change `.ssection_holder2 .price_table .price` to `.xssection_holder2 .price_table .price`, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All radio buttons have the same value of 9.99

No way to differentiate when the Browser has to decide which one to light up.

They must each have unique values.

I disabled javaScript and the problem is still there, so it's not jQuery.

I copied the form into another page by itself and it works in Chrome.

I have narrowed it down to stylesheet issue.

This is the stylesheet causing the problem.

`gia-online.com/banjac/css/style.css`

If you remove this stylesheet the problem goes away along with most of your styling.

This is cause of the problem:

```
<div class="section_holder2 two">
```

I changed it to:

```
<div class="xsection_holder2 two">
```

And the problem went away.

This is the line of CSS causing the problem:

```
.ssection_holder2 .price_table .price { 
color: #161616; 
font-size: 45px; 
font-weight: bold; 
line-height: 5px; 
text-align: center; 
padding: 8px 0px 8px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e5e5; 
}
```